# Java 8 Optional in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, java8

I like the idea of [Optional](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) in Java which we can use to say that the object may or may not be available.

I am now learning JavaScript and when trying to find an equivalent, came only across [optional-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/optional-js). No other major frameworks seem to be implementing that.

This caused me to wonder, is such a usage not needed in JavaScript? Is there an alternative in JavaScript for that? Is it not the `JavaScript way` of doing things?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it took *Java* a decade to go from having everything necessary to cleanly support it (i.e. since Java 5) to adding it; C# *still* hasn't added it to the standard library though it's been able to for about as long; and the idea has been in common use in (statically typed) functional languages since, at least, the '70s, I would actually say JavaScript is more representative of the trend.

Indeed, dynamically typed languages tend to be worse about this.  The concept is certainly useful in dynamically typed languages, and is easy to implement, but few have it in the "standard" libraries.  One of the reasons is that some of the benefits are lost in a dynamically typed language.  In a statically typed language, use of an `Optional` type will force me to handle the "nothing" case, not so in a dynamically typed language.

Another aspect that's a double whammy is the relative commonness of the notion of ["truthy"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) values.  On the one hand, it makes it significantly easier to silently get the wrong behavior when using something like `Optional`.  On the other hand, certain patterns that `Optional` can handle nicely can be accomplished by using truthiness, e.g. the ubiquitous

```
var x = passedInValue || defaultValue;
```

Still, it's not hard to imagine how the above could go wrong. "What if `passedInValue` is `0` or `false`?  Or what if I want it to be `null`? How do I communicate the difference between not providing a value and explicitly providing a null value?"  Similar issues happen when using a function: "How do I tell the difference between a look up failing and a look up successfully returning null?"  Arguably, in JavaScript, `undefined` could (seemingly) serve some of these roles, but it's a "solution" that's worse than the disease and also not a solution.

The situation is very much like `null` in most languages or `NULL` in SQL.  Truthiness amplifies the problems of `null`.  It may come as no surprise at this point that most statically typed functional languages lack an equivalent to `null`.  For some reason, after decades of existence, I'm not aware of any statically typed functional language that decided to *add* something like `null` after the creation of the language.

So, indeed, the answer is it's not the "JavaScript way" of doing things, but JavaScript was never really a leader in doing things in good ways.  Unfortunately, for this particular example, JavaScript is far from alone.  Somehow I doubt that `Optional` wouldn't have been useful in Java a decade ago.

Comment: Would you `recommend` using the above construct in JavaScript though?

Comment: @Can'tTell If it was commonly available, I would definitely use it.  If I was using something like TypeScript or Flow in an application, I would *definitely* use it even if I defined it myself. However, if I was making a library or working with a larger group of other developers writing "idiomatic" JavaScript, I'd probably not use it (unless the point of the library was to attempt to shift what "idiomatic" JavaScript means).

Comment: I am working on my own project. So based on your comment, I think I will use it. Thanks